# Fix the alignment of div in any screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the HTML code

```css
    .Box {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 60px;
      right: 0px;
      left: 65px;
      display: block;
      background-color: #fedd2d;
      max-width: 60%;
      padding: 15px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Box">
  <div class="Boxtitle">Hello</div>
  <div class="Boxsubtitle">Subtitle</div>
</div>
```

When I view this box on larger resolution (2560*1440) it expands both right side and left side. I tried using the width attribute which fixes the box from right side but the fix width hinders the responsiveness and the box width doesn't change with the length of the text within. 
How can I make this Box div stay in same position in any screen size using either CSS or Javascript, also making it responsive as per the length of the content in it?

Comment: To clarify, you want the box to be positioned 60px from the bottom and 65px from the left, and to have it's width defined by the width of its content?

Comment: Yes, you got it correct. Basically this div is aligned with another div below it. So left:60px looks perfect at resolution 1600 * 860, but at higher resolution it moves more left and the alignment destroys. How can I fix the  box to look same at any resolution.

Comment: That sounds different than what I described. It might help if you include the other `<div>` in your code to help demonstrate the problem you're having.

Comment: It is just the same kind of div, here is the code for simplification   <html><head><style>.Box2
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 65px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fedd2d;
    max-width: 60%;
    padding: 15px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}</style></head><body> <div class="Box2"><div class="Boxtitle">Foo-Bar</div><div class="Boxsubtitle">Subtitle</div></div></body></html>

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove the `right` and `max-width` and then the width will adjust based on the content.

```
.Box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 65px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fedd2d;
    padding: 15px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Well, this allows the box to be as per size of content, but it moves towards a little left on bigger resolution, which spoils the alignment of this div and the div below. Is there a way that this div stays at the same place at any screen resolution?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the other div code, but you could keep the ```right: 0;``` to pin the div to the right edge.

Answer (score 0):

`right:0;` seems to be in the way. it will pull container all the way to right side, but max-width is set too, so it stops at 60% of width as set. You rules are not coherent together.

since absolute, display is not really needed.

unless i missunderstand and max-width is in the way , ... or else ?

```css
.Box {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 60px;
      left: 65px;
      background-color: #fedd2d;
      max-width: 60%;
      padding: 15px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Box">
  <div class="Boxtitle">Hello</div>
  <div class="Boxsubtitle">Subtitle</div>
</div>

`
```